# System crash using Nitrogen

Tags: unity, 16.04

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04.

Steps:

- Installed unity-tweak-tool
- Numix icons
- Custom theme: https://github.com/vooze/arc-darker-ubuntu
- Installed Nitrogen
- Terminal:

  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
- Used Nitrogen to set a random wallpaper in my dual screen setup.
- Here it crashes when I exit Nitrogen window, everything becomes unresponsive.
- Fun fact is, when I reboot my logitech G105 bricks, my logitech mouse and keyboard stops working until I take out the power from the computer and hold the power button for some seconds, then reboot, and the keyboard/mouse work again, the wallpaper is not there (default one)

So I know this is not Ubuntu, but I'm completely lost, not sure what is causing the problem, any idea how to find the problem? (Maybe this is not even the place, sorry in that case)